# Popup is not appearing when used page_action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Google Chrome extension development. I am having the two following queries

1. Popup is not appearing when I use `page_action` in manifest.json but appearing when I used `browser_action`. I would like to know why? Or am I doing wrong
2. Also the icon is showing inactive state. Where as when I use `browser_action`, the icon is showing in active state (means I could see the color if active, or I could see as black and white icon, when inactive)

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title":"getStarted Extension"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [Teepemm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336725/teepeemm) . Followed his explanation and added the answer with code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to [Teepemm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336725/teepeemm) for guiding me with proper explanation, so in order to make the icon active and inactive, you have to use `chrome.pageAction.show(tabId)` (to activate the icon) and `chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId)` (to deactivate the icon) => https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show

You need to call this method from background.js by invoking it from client.js

```
//background.js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === "activate_icon") {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
});

//content-script.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "activate_icon"});
```

So once your extension icon is active, on click of the icon, popup will appear. So the popup will appear only when icon is active.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Gopinath Shiva I'm even having same issue. So, after adding the 2 js files any changes to be made in the `manifest.json` files or popup.js ?

Answer (score 9):

You need to use a background page (or better, event page) to call [`chrome.pageAction.show`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show).

You've chosen an unfortunate time to develop a chrome page action.  Google [recently changed](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-extensions/upcoming/chromium-extensions/7As9MKhav5E/dNiZDoSCCQAJ) how page actions work, and the documentation hasn't really caught up.  Previously, page actions appeared in the address bar, and only appeared on tabs where you had called `show`.  Now, page actions appear to the right of the address bar (unless you move them into the chrome menu), are always present, but are only active when you call `show`.  So the functions are still called `show` and `hide`, even though their effect is more akin to `enable` and `disable`.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! You just answered my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898206/chrome-extension-page-action-behaves-like-browser-action-not-showing-in-addres! Also a helpful link: http://thenextweb.com/apps/2016/03/04/google-chrome-bans-extensions-from-the-address-bar-forcing-them-to-the-side/