# Chrome extension: page_action behaves like browser_action (not showing in address bar)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have written a Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/commentanywhereorg/popgjmfoablgkolkhmnicijimhpifega
that has a ["`page_action`"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) (and not a [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)!) in it's manifest.

I had loaded the extension into the Chrome store beginning of February and the icon always appeared in the address bar of Chrome, next to the bookmark/favorite star icon, as planned:

[image]

**Since two weeks** or so (and without having made any changes or update to the extension), **the icon now always appears in the icon bar right next to the address bar, and not in the address bar anymore**, as if it would be declared as a "`browser_action`", but it's not!

[image]

Maybe it's due to a Chrome update, I'm on the latest version 49.0.2623.87. I already uninstalled and re-installed the extension, without any change.

Did Google change the behaviour of page actions? Does anyone know? How to get the icon back into the address bar?

What I also find confusing is the documentation on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction:

> Use the chrome.pageAction API to put icons **inside the address bar**.
>   Page actions represent actions that can be taken on the current page,
>   but that aren't applicable to all pages.

but their screenshots shows the icon outside of the address bar (in their example, the RSS icon):

[image]

My extension manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CommentAnywhere.org",
  "description": "CommentAnywhere.org allows you to comment anywhere on the web using your Facebook account.",
  "icons": {
     "128": "icon_128x128.png",
     "48": "icon_48x48.png",
     "32": "icon_32x32.png",
     "16": "icon_16x16.png"
  },
  "version": "1.4.1",
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_32x32.png",
    "default_title": "CommentAnywhere.org",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It is a chrome update.  And i hate it too.  Read: http://thenextweb.com/apps/2016/03/04/google-chrome-bans-extensions-from-the-address-bar-forcing-them-to-the-side/

Comment: Thanks for that link! Unfortunately they didn't update the documentation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer in another SO topic - with a different headline though - therefore missed it in the first place.
Thanks to user Teepeemm.

[Popup is not appearing when used page_action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882089/popup-is-not-appearing-when-used-page-action/35882614#35882614)

> Google recently changed how page actions work, and the documentation
>   hasn't really caught up. Previously, page actions appeared in the
>   address bar, and only appeared on tabs where you had called show.

And a helpful link from Marc Guiselin clarifies it as well: http://thenextweb.com/apps/2016/03/04/google-chrome-bans-extensions-from-the-address-bar-forcing-them-to-the-side/

Comment: A link to Google announcing the change: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-extensions/upcoming/chromium-extensions/7As9MKhav5E/dNiZDoSCCQAJ